# Getting NullPointerException while skipping login Activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I want to skip login activity using shared preferences but whenever I try to implement this code `java.lang.nullpointerexception` error occur. This is a java code of launch or login screen. here i have no splash screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button sub;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    EditText useret,pwdet;
    String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(this.isLoggedIn()==true) {
            checklogin();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        useret=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etuser);
        pwdet=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpwd);
        sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String username=useret.getText().toString();
                String password=pwdet.getText().toString();
                prefs=getSharedPreferences("codelearn_twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("key_for_username",username);
                editor.putString("key_for_passwrd",password);
                editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
                editor.commit();

                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,listactivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
    public void checklogin(){
        if(this.isLoggedIn()==true){
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,listactivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return prefs.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

below is a list of error..

> 08-19 17:58:17.061  14978-14978/com.example.viren.codelearn
>                                  E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>            Process: com.example.viren.codelearn, PID: 14978
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>           ComponentInfo {com.example.viren.codelearn/com.example.vire
>           n.codelearn.MainActivity}:java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>           (ActivityThread.java:2305)
>            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>            (ActivityThread.java:2363)
>            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
>            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>            (ActivityThread.java:1265)
>            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>            (ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.viren.codelearn.MainActivity.isLoggedIn
>            (MainActivity.java:56)
>               at com.example.viren.codelearn.MainActivity.onCreate
>            (MainActivity.java:23)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>            (Instrumentation.java:1105)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>              (ActivityThread.java:2269)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>                   (ActivityThread.java:2363)

Comment: try doing if(this.isLoggedIn()==true) { checklogin(); } after setContentView is called.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't ever check a boolean value with an equal-to operator against true/false. That's just silly. `if(this.isLoggedIn()){...}`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your stacktrace, you can see that at line 56 you call **isLoggedIn** which calls your **prefs** variable, that is not initialized yet (it's null), thus your getting the null pointer exception.

Make the **prefs** variable accesible for your whole class, and initialize it before calling **isLoggedIn** or initialize it inside the **isLoggedIn** method.

Answer (score 0):

your prefs are not initialized at that point... 
you must

```
 prefs=getSharedPreferences("codelearn_twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

before returning

```
return prefs.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you called `isLoggedIn()` which returns the value from Shared Preferences but the shared preferences instance is not initialized yet and is null so before calling

```
if(this.isLoggedIn()==true) {
        checklogin();
    }
```

you must initialize shared preference variable

```
prefs=getSharedPreferences("codelearn_twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

That is :

```
 prefs=getSharedPreferences("codelearn_twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);

 if(this.isLoggedIn()==true) {
            checklogin();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to initialize your SharedPreferences first before calling it.

## Move this:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("codelearn_twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

## Above this:

```
if (this.isLoggedIn() == true) {
    checklogin();
}
```

## To be like this:

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("codelearn_twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);

if (this.isLoggedIn() == true) {
    checklogin();
}
```